# Does denying creeps earns XP for opposing team?

Tags: dota-2

Is it true that denied creeps still give XP to heroes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, denied creeps still give experience to opposing heroes, although not as much as if they had died another way.

[From the wiki:](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Creep_control_techniques#Denying_Creeps)

> A denied creep divides 36 exp to enemy heroes within 1300 range. A melee\ranged creep would normally give 62\41 exp in 1300 range respectively.

So denied melee creep only give the enemy 58% of its experience bounty, and denied ranged creeps only give 88% of theirs.

Some abilities are exceptions to this. Lich's Sacrifice splits the full experience between all heroes on both teams in XP range. Some abilities that consume creeps can deny all experience.

Comment: that wiki is goddamn bad. i just edited the mechanics section because it was old information. that forced me to deliver 1 min after you...

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of denying a creep.

## Lasthitting an allied creep

this method does reduce the xp the enemy will get to 36 divided between enemy heroes in a 1300 AoE.

## Using a spell on an allied creep

Depends on the spell

### Both teams get full xp

Sacrifice

### Fully denies the enemy xp

Demonic Conversion

Death Pact